# How to group values in matrix with items of unequal length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grouping

Lets say I have a simple array:

```
a = np.arange(3)
```

And an array of indices with the same length:

```
I = np.array([0, 0, 1])
```

I now want to group the values based on the indices.
How would I group the elements of the first array to produce the result below?

```
np.array([[0, 1], [2], dtype=object)
```

---

Here is what I tried:

```
a = np.arange(3)
I = np.array([0, 0, 1])
out = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
out.fill([])

aslists = np.vectorize(lambda x: [x], otypes=['object'])

out[I] += aslists(a)
```

However, this approach does not concatenate the lists, but only maintains the last value for each index:

```
array([[1], [2]], dtype=object)
```

---

Or, for a 2-dimensional case:

```
a = np.random.rand(100)
I = (np.random.random(100) * 5 //1).astype(int)
J = (np.random.random(100) * 5 //1).astype(int)

out = np.empty((5, 5), dtype=object)
out.fill([])
```

How can I append the items from a to out based on the two index arrays?

Comment: At the moment it is not, but I can sort it, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1D Case**

Assuming `I` being sorted, for a list of arrays as output -

```
idx = np.unique(I, return_index=True)[1]
out = np.split(a,idx)[1:]
```

Another with `slicing` to get `idx` for splitting `a` -

```
out = np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(I[1:] != I[:-1])+1)
```

To get an array of lists as output -

```
np.array([i.tolist() for i in out])
```

Sample run -

```
In [84]: a = np.arange(3)

In [85]: I = np.array([0, 0, 1])

In [86]: out = np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(I[1:] != I[:-1])+1)

In [87]: out
Out[87]: [array([0, 1]), array([2])]

In [88]: np.array([i.tolist() for i in out])
Out[88]: array([[0, 1], [2]], dtype=object)
```

---

**2D Case**

For `2D` case of filling into a `2D` array with groupings made from indices in two arrays `I` and `J` that represent the rows and columns where the groups are to be assigned, we could do something like this -

```
ncols = 5
lidx = I*ncols+J
sidx = lidx.argsort() # Use kind='mergesort' to keep order
lidx_sorted = lidx[sidx]
unq_idx, split_idx = np.unique(lidx_sorted, return_index=True)
out.flat[unq_idx] = np.split(a[sidx], split_idx)[1:]
```

Comment: Nice solutions! For my eventual application, I am looking for something similar, but my output array is 2-dimensional and I have an array of indices for both dimensions: I = np.array([0, 0, 1]); J = np.array([1, 0, 0]); out = np.empty((2, 2), dtype=object). Do you happen to know a solution to this as well?

Comment: @JohnDamen So, we would need to fill the not available ones with zeros or some other invalid specifier? I am guessing the output would be like : `[[0,1][2,NA]]`?

Comment: The lists may be uneven, the main point is grouping by the indices along 2 dimensions

Comment: Yes, that's it!